# Prevent json_encode to encode empty strings as null

Tags: php, json

Is it possible for the PHP `json_encode` function do not convert empty string values to null?

**UPDATE**
I can not replicate this behaviour in clear conditions, and looks like it's already a default for this function.

Comment: So far as I can see it doesn't convert empty string to null.  Do you have an example???

Comment: You're better to show your code (which you should do by default here on Stack Overflow).

Comment: one guy's `null` is another guy's `empty` string ? show the code please.

Comment: Yep, @DawidFerenczy without it looks like opinions divided ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already the default behavior.

```
json_encode(['test' => '']);
```

generates:

```
{"test":""}
```

Answer (score 1):

No that i know of, but you could do this:

```
array_walk_recursive($value, function (&$item, $key) {
    $item = null === $item ? '' : $item;
});
```

Comment: Yes I also saw this kind of code here http://developertipsandtricks.blogspot.com/2013/10/convert-null-to-empty-string-for-json.html
and it looks like eclipse of the mind, because I can't replicate this now in clear conditions )) So thank you but... Should I close this question?